# Output in the wrong order?

Tags: php, html

This is being output as...

```
'Customer Info...'

'Customer Accounts...'

[contents of $custOutput]

[contents of $accOutput]
```

```
<font size="2" align="center"><font color="silver">Customer Info...</font></font></h3>
<?php echo $custOutput; ?>
<br />
<font size="2" align="center"><font color="silver">Customer Accounts...</font></font></h3>
<?php echo $accOutput; ?>
```

Is there any reason why this isn't being output in the order written?
Expected output is

```
'Customer Info...'
[contents of $custOutput]

'Customer Accounts...'
[contents of $accOutput]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: Where is the other half of ending `</h3>` tags?

Comment: Invalid HTML does not produce predictable output.

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove the H3 tags fully....being doing a lot of chopping and changing. Result is the same with or without

Comment: If you have removed the two `</h3>` tags then there's no reason anymore, for the wrong output you see, _in code you've shown us_. That means there could be something wrong in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: A good first step in diagnosing this is to view the page source rather than the displayed page and see if the output is truly in the wrong order, or just being rendered that way due to problematic HTML. (You may have already done this.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that out by doing this,

```
 <font size="2" align="center">
  <font color="silver">Customer Info... <br />
  <?php echo $custOutput; ?>
  </font>
</font>

<br />

 <font size="2" align="center">
  <font color="silver">Customer Account... <br />
  <?php echo $custOutput; ?>
  </font>
</font>
```

P.S if you dont want to use `<br>` inside `<font>`, you can wrap your php code inside `<p><?php echo $VAR; ?> </p>` since `<p>` tag is a block level element by default in its nature, although if u are using normalizers or all of the elements are set to display inline, then you would have to add `css` property `display:block` on p tag.

Comment: I'm guessing that the op only wanted to make the headings (i.e., Customer Info..., etc.) in the silver font color. In that case, I would of closed out the silver font tag before adding the break.